# GridView Header Text in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, header, dynamic

I want to change the header text of the gridview using Design from `<TemplateField HeaderText="">`.

I created a variable in code behind which is public and set the value in that variable and then I tried to call that variable over here as below:

```
<TemplateField HeaderText = '<%= VariableCallHere %>'
```

But while running the page, I got <%= VariableCallHere %> as a header text.

Even I tried changing using `gridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "text Here"` (This Throws object reference error)

Any one have any suggestions how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be `gridview1.Columns[ColumnIndex].HeaderText = "Header text";`

Comment: I wanted to set the header text based upon logic for the dataRows (after the Header row) and this did nothing but `gridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[ColumnIndex].Text` did work. I don't understand, but useful for anyone else struggling with this.

Answer (score 4):

For this, in the RowDataBound event of the gridview control you need
to write as like follows:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{
  e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "column 1";
  e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "column 2";
  .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Access it via the columns collection:

```
gridview1.Columns[Index].HeaderText= "text Here";
```

As in:

```
gridview1.Columns[0].HeaderText= "text Here";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it like this for multilingual it works fine NO need of extra work for iterating the rows just put it there and let it do the work

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="TITLE_NAME" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Site,lblTitleName %>"
                            ItemStyle-Width="20%">
   <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {                
            Label lblAddInText = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblAddInText");
            lblAddInText.Text = "ADD IN TEXT" 
        }
```

in RowCreated Event of Gridview. Using  and Label in .