# How do I specify the column name for a gridview explicitly?

Tags: asp.net, linq

Here is my simple LINQ query which returns one row and I am binding it to the grid view. By default the column name which I get in grid view is "ITEM". How do I change it to custom name ?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int[] a = {10,20,30,40,50 };
        var iList =from n in a
                   where n>10
                    select n;
        _gridView1.DataSource = iList;
        _gridView1.DataBind();
}
```

My output:

[image]

Comment: how u define gridview in aspx page

Comment: I just dragged and dropped the grid view into my web page and im using it...

Comment: Then do it like that. Learn to modify the generated code (or write it from scratch), it's a matter of changing few lines of code... This is pure laziness...

Answer (score 0):

```
string colName="Custom Col Name";
_gridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = colName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HeaderText property for this. Look here for more details: [GridView Header Text in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476148/gridview-header-text-in-asp-net)